# What should the predefined off-topic reasons be for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, scope

As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) (and elaborated on [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns)), we're preparing to roll out some fairly major changes to how closing works that will allow for pre-defined, site-specific off-topic reasons.

On a site with as much history as Stack Overflow, defining the exact boundaries of what is on- and off-topic can be a real challenge. Rather than trusting my gut on this, I sat down and analyzed a random sampling of recently-closed questions, wrote up a handful of reasons that covered the bulk of them, and then threw them at the moderators for feedback. After some discussion and several revisions, this is what I'm suggesting for the initial rollout:

#### Custom off-topic close reasons

1. Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

   *this was the most commonly asked off-topic topic, even excluding questions that were eventually migrated*
2. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

   *Not every question involves a specific chunk of code, but if it does that code must be included, as short as possible, and understood well enough by the asker to allow for a descriptive title; "here's my code, find the bug" questions should be closed ASAP - this covers the bulk of [reasonable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168775/is-the-too-localized-description-inconsistent-with-the-communitys-de-facto-st/168778#168778) Too Localized closures.*
3. Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

   *this complements reason #2 for questions that **don't** involve already-written code. If you're asking others to solve a problem for you, you must be able to understand and communicate it well enough to allow useful answers to be written and found by others.**
4. Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

   *There's no longer a migration path from SO to SF, but that doesn't stop folks from asking system administration questions on SO. Disturbingly, a lot of questions on programming tools get closed for this reason because certain folks think development servers are at all like the real deal - this* might *help to discourage that.*
5. Questions asking for **tool or library recommendations** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [Describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

   *This one is long overdue*

---

I should also note that once the new system is rolled out, we'll be able to query and analyze the reasons provided via [the "other" off-topic option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185088/the-default-off-topic-close-reason-cannot-be-selected-from-the-new-close-dialo/185101#185101) in a fairly simple fashion - I fully expect to be tweaking and changing these reasons fairly quickly based on observed usage. But that doesn't mean we shouldn't try to hit as many common mistakes as possible right out of the gate, so...

Thoughts? Improvements? Concerns?

Comment: It's still unclear to me why reason #3 is specific to questions regarding assignments. Not that I disagree or agree, since I can't really do that until I understand its rationale.

Comment: I agree with BoltClock... that close reason might be more widely applicable as "SO is not a *plz send teh codez* website. We expect users to have a basic understanding of the problem, and to have attempted to solve the problem at hand themselves first"

Comment: @Bolt: it's simple: those were the sorts of questions I observed being *closed* for this reason.

Comment: Ah, as opposed to others that were getting downvoted only but left open to answers. Makes sense now.

Comment: Number 3 is really a good idea, I'd even venture that the original premise for SO was that you'd have minimal understanding of the problem area before asking a question. The examples I have seen from Joel when he is asked what SO is about are all like this: "I have this regex, but it doesn't cover this case", or "how do I do a 64-bit integer multiplication in assembler?" Nice to see the requirement in writing. Like @BoltClock'saUnicorn I wonder why it should be confined to "assignments", though. Edited: Ah, I see Shog9's explanation now, although I'm not sure it would hurt to make it general.

Comment: We can always broaden these, @Monolo; I think it covers an awful lot of ground as it stands though. Given the whole purpose of the change is to increase the *specificity* of these reasons, I tend to think it's worth seeing how they play out in practice before generalizing too much. FWIW, I'm kinda trying to [eat my own dogfood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184637/what-do-site-moderators-need-to-do-to-support-the-new-custom-question-close-reas/185097#185097) here...

Comment: Looks great. ♥ Numbers 2 and 3. Evil powers will try to cut them down. Please defend at all costs. :)

Comment: Point taken about #2, and while I think these close reasons will work really well, just a small observation about #5: The wording "library" may not be part of all of the intended audience's vocabulary - many web platforms don't use that name, but call them packages, frameworks, etc. instead. I wonder if it would be worthwhile adapting to that nomenclature? Web development is after all the gateway drug of programming.

Comment: Could we stuff books in #5?

Comment: @Monolo I think they'd be able to figure out, from context, what's going on.  I really don't forsee a whole lot of meta posts along the lines of "I'm not asking for a library recommendation, I'm asking for a *framework* recommendation.  Reopen my question NOW!!!"

Comment: Can you help me to understand this a bit better? If Too Localized was ok to use for syntax errors (misspelled variables, missing semicolons, etc.), and Too Localized has now been subsumed into Off Topic, which of these would I use in that circumstance? Or would I have to use a custom off topic reason...?

Comment: @joran #2.  See shog9's comment, "this a close second, covering the bulk of Too Localized closures"

Comment: @Servy Ok, I'm happy to use that reason, but I think it will be weird, as many of those typo questions are quite well formed, with a concise, reproducible example, and the OP will have described exactly what error they're getting. They just haven't realized the cause.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Perhaps I'm part of the OP-loving/evil powers you fear, but I'm not arguing with 2 or 3 (or any of this very-well-thought-out list). They're well phrased too.

Comment: @Shog9 This is a very good list.  Don't know what happened between yesterday and today, but this list is much better than the last version I saw.  "regarding assignments" can be dropped from reason #3.

Comment: Your feedback happened, @Robert. Big thanks to all the SO mods for their help on this.

Comment: "Book requests" tend to be a bit of a different beast, @Mat - the most problematic ones are probably better addressed with "too opinion-based". *Tutorial* requests are a lot closer to what #5 is addressing though.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm not sure I see that much of a difference. You sometimes get questions asking for "tutorials, books, videos, examples or links for whatever". I guess the "too opinion-based" reason is ok for this, but IMO your #5 addresses the issue with resource requests better (and avoids "But I _am_ looking for references, from people with expertise in whatever, why did you close this?"). How about "[...] tool, library or resource recommendations [...]"?

Comment: These are great! Looking forward to having this specificity and clarity on the closing banners. Very nice work! Now we [just need to change the heading for them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185109/159251).

Comment: 3 is a specialization of 2.  4 is a specialization of 1.  You can roll the specializations into the general reasons and add the text together.  We shouldn't be splitting hairs on close reasons that are essentially the same thing.

Comment: I disagree that #4 is a general OT case, @casperOne; if anything, the fact that we had to remove SF as a migration target because folks kept migrating questions that *weren't* appropriate indicates that it isn't - consider the case of [tag:htaccess] questions, of which there are many, many more on SO than on SF but which still get flagged and closed as off-topic with some regularity; if a question is being closed because a voter feels it falls into the systems admin camp, then that needs to be *explicit*.

Comment: @Shog9 That's just splitting hairs, and frankly, if it's a *new* question that belongs on one of these other sites that needs an explicit reason, then we should be *migrating* it.

Comment: I'm less concerned about the ones that are actually off-topic than the ones that aren't, @casperOne.

Answer (score 30):

You can drop the 'regarding assignments' text.

Whether it's an assignment or homework doesn't matter; it could even be a professional question ([How do I move the turtle in logo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)).  The point is, we want people to have tackled the problem themselves, first.

> Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: That LOGO question is anything but professional ಠ_ಠ

Comment: The turtle in LOGO! Slowly I turned. Inch by inch, step by step...

Comment: After thinking about this for a while longer, I've revised #3 to drop "assignments" and clarify what is required. This broadens the coverage somewhat; I'll be keeping an eye on how it is used in practice.

Answer (score 26):

### Please rename "Off Topic" to "Site-Specific Reason", or "Off-limits"

There seems to be some degree of angst on these questions and answers over using "Off Topic" for some of these close reasons, whilst there is much less angst about the reasons themselves.

1 (SuperUser), 4 (ServerFault) and 5 (Recommendations) say "off topic" in the text and this is fine.
2 (code dump) and 3 (assignment dump) don't say off topic in the text, but are nevertheless closable.

If we're having this much argument over the use of the phrase "Off Topic" ahead of time, I think we can expect a similar level of "how come my code is off topic on a programming site?" meta questions as "why is this question not constructive?", and for the same reason:

**If you extend the meaning of a phrase in a close reason to cover something else, you end up having a pointless argument about the phrase** instead of a helpful discussion of the question or indeed simply a quiet edit.

An accurate name encourages accurate use. The new use of Off Topic is for site-specific reasons. Some of those are because the question is about the wrong thing altogether (usual meaning of off-topic), and some are because we know we don't want that type of question (more likely to be called off limits than off topic). Together these are simply "site-specific reasons", and should be called that.

(I'd accept that "Off-limits" is a replacement which would more readily be substituted because it can be used in similar phrases "your question is off-limits because...", and we still avoid the problem with the word "topic".)

I haven't figured out whether I think the free-text custom reason should be described as "Off Topic", "Site-specific reason" or simply left completely open for the closer to type whatever they like. Given the uses we're planning on putting Off Topic to, I suspect we want to allow custom reasons that are not simply that the question is not about programming. Here again, Off-limits may be easier to use.

Comment: You may be interested in [Can we rename the off topic close reason label on the primary screen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024) if you haven't already seen it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes; thanks ...... and _thanks_. :)

Comment: Thank _you_ for crystallizing the explanation of the problems with the "Off Topic" heading.

Answer (score 6):

There are two (of my) use cases for NARQ which I am not clear how they would be mapped to these reasons.

The first was mentioned by joran in a comment: the typo question. The question itself may be well formed with reproducible code and a stated error message. The answer is that there was a typographical error in the code: a missing semicolon, a misspelled parameter name, an incorrectly placed close of a code block, etc. These are legitimate questions (person asking had a real problem, well stated), with an answer that is helpful to the person asking, but the answers would not be helpful to anyone in the future because no one is likely to have that exact typo, and even if they did it would be impossible to find the appropriate question. Should these be closed under one of the listed reasons, or is it expected that the "other" reason would be used for these?

The second use case is questions where the answer ends up being that the problem is a result of a bug or error in the underlying program/library used, not in the asking person's code. The answer is then to update the underlying software to a newer version (which may not have existed when the question was asked because the question triggered finding and fixing the bug). This question is only marginally useful for future readers because, as time goes on, more and more people will have the updated version of the software which has the bug fixed. As with the previous use case, is this expected to go under the "other", should it have its own reason, or does it fit in which one of the already given reasons?

Comment: But not all typo questions are TL: imagine someone who muddles up comma and semi colon in C++ for example. The compiler error message may not make sense to the coder, but searching SO could lead to someone's typo question and thus enlightenment. Only when the typo is really not going to help anyone (you declared Count but are using Cont) should it be closed - and offtopic feels a little strange for those since you don't know that until it's been answered.

Comment: For the second case, I just don't see why they should be closed.  Framework bugs are actually rather likely to affect other people, and be interesting or helpful to future readers.  Old versions of frameworks stay in (often heavy) use for many years for mainstream languages.

Comment: @KateGregory That is _exactly_ the example I've been trying to articulate.

Comment: @Servy Not in every domain, they don't. Questions about bugs in versions of R >1 year old are virtually useless.

Comment: re bugs: You're suggesting closing a question __now__ because it'll probably be less useful in the _future_. Using this reasoning, we would close a question because it uses something that someone filed a feature request to be deprecated. Until it's been deprecated for long enough that hardly anyone's using it, the Q/A have value. Similarly, "No, actually, that's a bug, work around it (this way...)" is useful. "Bug fixed in previous release; just update" is still a relevant and helpful answer. _New_ bugs should be left for linking duplicates to, and _current_ non-dupe bugs are also helpful.

Comment: @KateGregory I think you make a good distinction between different types of typo questions. Those where the nature of the typo can be determined directly from the error message do serve a purpose (since search on that error message leads to an explanation of how to fix the problem). They should not be closed. Where the error message is not informative of the root problem, or where there is no error but unanticipated/incorrect behavior, they are not useful to anyone else and closure is warranted.

Comment: `Obsolete` seems a better way of dealing with it's-a-bug, once it is out of date. See [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185120/194906).

Comment: @AndrewC The situation he was thinking of re:bugs was something that's relatively common in R, i.e. someone pops up with a well stated question describing some problem, no one can reproduce it, and then it turns out they're using a very old version of R or a package. The usefulness of these sorts of questions will vary between languages (a problem we have to live with on SO) but _in R_ they really are quite useless to future Googlers.

Comment: @joran If there are so many questions about old versions of R, how can you conclude they're not useful to other visitors? Would `Obsolete` not be appropriate?

Comment: @AndrewC My only concern is that _when_ I vote to close these Q's, that the reason description not be absurdly non-descriptive, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple scenario to consider. I would like to ask you a question: Build me a paper airplane. Was my question off topic? Did I ask a question?

Apparently there is consensus to use "Off Topic" as an umbrella reason to close questions. I don't agree that is a correct path to take because it will confuse people and cause scope creep for "subreasons".

However, we are there. `<`insert analogy to joining if not beating`>`.  And at the very least I would like to agree with the Close reason "Off Topic" subreason #3 with regards to "assignments" (Requests for work). I agree with George when he said "we want people to have tackled the problem themselves", and believe that the wording could be improved to aim for that type of scenario.

> #### 3. "Questions regarding implementing features must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the technology, and include an attempt to solve the problem."

Comment: FWIW, this isn't something we just pulled out of thin air; folks have *already been using OT in this fashion* for quite a long while. The name may not be quite right, but naming is hard and this is what folks are already used to, so...

Comment: Also, I don't like "include an attempt to solve the problem" or any other euphemism for "post code". Code is important when the problem is in the code; as a proxy for demonstrating a basic understanding of the problem you're solving, it sucks. One of the most frustrating things I've seen with Too Localized was its use on questions that didn't include code ("not enough effort!") ...and then again on similar questions that did ("too specific to your code!") Damned if you do, damned if you don't...

Comment: @Shog9 - With regards to using "Off Topic" as an umbrella, this is just my opinion. I completely understand the issue of going with what is the best option which this seems to be.

Comment: @Shog9 - As for the "post code" request, where does it say code in the text? I am talking about an attempt, either in psuedo, as a description of what they tried, something. I think that questions are sometimes too aggressively closed and that is unfortunate. That is another issue though. There are a lot of questions which come in that ask the community to do the work with only supplying the requirements. How else can we politely but forcefully close and prevent those questions?

Comment: Here's a question for you: do you feel [this author has demonstrated sufficient effort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539246/css-3d-transforms) He's certainly gone a bit further than simply demanding a plane...

Comment: @Shog9 - Good example. The OP does not seem to be a help vampire to me. They have invested a lot of time into a feature already which seems pretty neat (By the way, very cool finding a coded airplane example). They have one caveat that they cannot seem to get working and ask for an approach. The answer provides a rather ingenious approach to folding content based off of css margins, but the answers aren't really what is in question. This does not feel like a request for work to me because the OP has done so much already and has a very small specific circumstance outlined.

Comment: that's my take too (the title could use some love, but it's not a show-stopper). And this is what I'd like to encourage: questions that simply show that the asker has thought about the problem a bit.

Comment: @Shog9 - I would actually like to see some effort, not just thought. Although the OP in the example did not provide the exact work produced (which isn't always necessary), he provided his process that he was using already. It definitely showed effort. I feel like many times people get an idea and then post "how can I implement this idea". There can be a lot of thought behind it, but it should be up to them to actually implement the idea, not the community. Without any effort, there is nothing we can do. If they get stuck then that is where we can step in and help them out. Is that too strict?

Comment: Define "effort", @Travis. Where do you draw the line between thought and effort when both are expressed via text typed into a computer?

Comment: @Shog9 - In my opinion: It definitely depends heavily on context. In an algorithm, defining what your train of thought was could be seen as effort. This would satisfy the "attempt to solve" clause listed in my answer. However, when talking specifically about a programming question where code is involved, I think that it is very easy to define effort. Effort: Either code was shown or the approach was outlined. No-Effort: No code was shown, and no approach was outlined - even though a solution was requested.

Comment: @Shog9 - What do you think of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17266288/1026459 ?

Comment: I think it's fine, @Travis. I would prefer the JSFiddle code was embedded, but in this case it's not essential to the question.

Comment: Oh, and @Travis: regarding showing effort for code you're working on... That's the entire focus of reason #2. In one of the first drafts for this, there was a lot more overlap between #2 and #3, but I backed away from that a bit (and may go further yet) because they're separate (though related) problems and the *last* thing I want to do is encourage more folks to post code just for the sake of satisfying an arbitrary requirement (I've seen too many questions made worse by the inclusion of a block consisting of nothing but an empty function or program shell with "logic I need goes here" in it).

Comment: @Shog9 - I don't think code should be a requirement. There should at least be an explanation of the attempt though. I guess that is the "tell us what you tried" part of #3. Out of curiosity, how far away are we from these changes being published to stackoverflow?

Comment: @Shog9 - In response to the linked question (10k+). Note that it is now deleted because it was not a good question. It was a request for work. However, you seem to be of the impression these requests are to be allowed now? As long as I show what I was thinking. "I am trying to make a UI where the user can control a dynamic list of addresses." And they show some code. "Here is my view model that I am binding to" What is the best way to implement the UI? You think that is a) a question, b) "on topic", c) worthy of an answer?

Comment: that example was deleted by its author, without being closed, flagged or even down-voted; I wouldn't put too much weight on that. As for the on-topicness of this *type* of question... There are thousands of them doing just fine on SO and have been for years.

Comment: @Shog9 - Sorry to persist at this, I am clearly confused on this topic. Just so I have this correct, it is perfectly fine to post requests for work as questions as long as the question is properly worded and documented?

Answer (score 2):

Can something to cover reverse engineering questions be added?

Questions like:

> I'm trying to X as seen on site/program/app Y. How do I do it?

These questions tend to get down-voted and closed often enough, see examples [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184200/217863).

I've raised [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184200/217863) about adding these to the list of "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"

The response to that question was:

> There is a close reason being refined that deals with this, basically
>   saying that questions that just point to third party code without
>   including any specific bits and end in 'how do I do what they did?'
>   aren't on topic. It's not yet baked, so I'm not yet officially
>   answering - but this is one of the cases we considered when coming up
>   with the initial set of close reasons for Stack Overflow. – Tim Post♦
>   Jun 13 at 1:04

Comment: I don't exactly see a whole lot of these.  Certainly not more than any of the ones listed above.  Note that "Unclear" pretty much applies to most of these types of questions (NARQ did before that).  If there isn't enough information in the question itself to answer it, that's the GOTO response.

Comment: @Servy If George Stoker's recommendation is implemented, I would guess these could fall under "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."

Comment: Sure, that could fit as well.

Comment: @Servy the problem is that many of these questions can reasonably be answered. It just requires the answerer to do all the leg work and they often rely entirely on third party links.

Comment: It's the "rely on external links" that would qualify it for closure.  If the information needed to answer is isn't *in the question* then it's lacking, for the same reason that an answer that's just a link isn't really answering the question in the eyes of the site.

Comment: I don't see a problem with these questions *when they include enough information to be answerable* - a screenshot, description of the desired functionality, etc. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657894/android-facebook-style-slide

Comment: @Shog9 I was referring more to this type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914729/how-to-make-image-map-popup-with-jquery. The question you pointed to is the first time I've seen one done well.

Comment: "Unclear" is fine for that, @apaul34208. It is an appallingly bad question regardless of topic. FWIW, I picked that example specifically because folks ask duplicates of it *all the time* - often very, very badly; therefore, the existence of *one good version* provides an instant close reason for those that follow.

Comment: @Shog9 I think even the question you pointed out, could be flagged with #3 as it doesn't really "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". Had it included some code and/or an attempt recreate what they were after, it would probably be fine. Don't these types of questions generally point to "code this for me" or "research this for me".

Comment: @apaul34208: I don't think being forced to include code *when you aren't asking for code to be written for you* makes any sense at all. The author described - using words and pictures and even a video - the behavior he wanted to replicate, indicating he had a basic understanding of what was happening; that should suffice.

Comment: @Shog9 after reading the comments on Travis J's answer, I think I've got a better idea of where you're coming from. Its the "build this for me" with just a link, that I guess I'm really tired of. You're right those questions are easily covered by other flag reasons.

Comment: "the problem is that many of these questions can reasonably be answered. It just requires the answerer to do all the leg work and they often rely entirely on third party links." ...exactly.  That makes it completely *on* topic, and problematic for *other* reasons.

Comment: @djechlin I've already conceded the point see the comment above yours

Comment: @djechlin - "That makes it completely on topic, and problematic for other reasons." There are no longer any reasons other than topicality for this scenario because of the changes to the close mechanism. Can you expand on what you meant by "problematic for other reasons" please?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about this post, so I wrote a [review in a separate post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185909/stackoverflows-close-off-topic-reasons-could-be-improved). Summary based on opinions here, my post and the comments to it:

- Options *describe the specific problem* and *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved* should be moved as sub-options of *unclear what you're asking*, as they are not "off-topic". Renaming "off-topic" to "off-limits" or "site-specific reasons" is probably okay, but I'd rather see a proper hierarchy of reasons.
- An alternative website should be added for *tool or library recommendations* option. That is, if there is any good website for comparisons like on Wikipedia ("C# vs Java", "Text editors" etc.) It should be a sub-option of *primarily opinion-based*, because that is exactly what it is. The linked question is not broad enough, [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) is more general.
- A list of another sites in the SE network should include Server Fault, for consistency. Maybe it should also include other websites, but I don't know statistics (maybe put all *technology* sites into the list?). This is a duplication, so the outcomes should still be the same, regardless of *how* SF or SU were recommended (I don't know how it works now).
- Period is missing in two of the options.

Additionally, after reading the post:

- *"Off-topic"* list is much more verbose than the list one level higher, which uses short and concise wording (*duplicate*, *off-topic*, *too broad*) with more detailed explanations in grey text. Compare this with:

  > Questions concerning problems with code you've written must *describe the specific problem* and include valid code to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

  It's totally not "describe the specific problem", it's "no code to reproduce" or just "need code".

  > Questions must *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved*. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

  Some folks hate the wording, but it's essentially "What have you tried?" -- no more, no less. Wether these exact words are displayed when a question is "on hold" is debatable, but I think it's perfectly valid as a short and concise title for the option.

  On the whole, formatting of the list should follow the formatting of the list one level higher.

Comment: Hahaha, downvoting without comments — now on meta too! Great.