# Why was this C network interface question put on hold as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-hold

This is regarding my recent question, *[How can I find the bridge device name for my tap adapter in C (Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36165017)*. It was placed on-hold, with the reason given as off-topic.

*(Please note that I have reworded the question to hopefully make clearer.)*

I'm looking for how to programmatically get information about a network interface on my Linux system using C. I have searched high and low for an answer, or least something pointing towards an answer. It *appears* that the information I am seeking is not a common problem; however, I believe that makes it even *more* on-topic and valuable for Stack Overflow, so that future people seeking a similar question might find the answer.

If my question is off-topic, why are the following questions not off-topic for Stack Overflow?

- *[Get IP address of an interface on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2283494)* (C, 45 votes, 3 answers)
- *[How do I output my host’s IP addresses from a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2021549)*  (C, 14 votes, 8 answers)
- *[How can I get to know the IP address for interfaces in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4139405)*  (C, 9 votes, 6 answers)
- *[How do I get my IP address in C on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20800319)* (C, 4 votes, 2 answers)
- *[C code to get the IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1570511)*  (C, 2 votes, 3 answers)
- *[Linux C: Get default interface's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17909401)* (C/C++, 2 votes, 2 answers)
- *[Get local IP address in C++ Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4130147)*  (C++, 2 votes, 4 answers)
- *[How to know the IP address for interfaces in C using IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420500)* (C, 0 votes, 1 answer)
- *[How do I get the network interface and its right IPv4 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9855230)*  (C#, 30 votes, 2 answers)
- *[Get IP address and adapter description using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13174909)* (C#, 4 votes, 1 answer)
- *[How do I get the local IP address in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23558425)* (Go, 11 votes, 2 answers)
- *[How to get the physical interface IP address from an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6243276)*  (Python, 13 votes, 3 answers)
- *[How can I get the IP address of eth0 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24196932)* (Python, 8 votes, 5 answers)

And for a variation on the theme, but it still amounts to a similar approach,

- *[Finding an interface name from an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427517)* (C/C++, 2 votes, 16 answers)

Comment: Because one user didn't understand your question, and then mob voting happened.

Comment: @CodeCaster did you read the original revision (the version that was closed)? It's a code request, or a "how do I start", etc. "What I've tried" came after the closure. You can argue that maybe that's still on-topic (like the mostly-old questions listed above), but that's not the same as mob-voting by reviewers confused by the question.

Comment: @Paul anyone familiar with the subject knows that the code is irrelevant. The original question, in order to not be closed with the stated reason, could only contain _"What to provide for `ioctl(...)`?"_ as relevant code. I'm not saying it's a particularly perfect question, but the close reason makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm familiar with the subject, I disagree, and I voted to reopen the edited question. I'm sure there's a No True Scotsman objection to all that, but I'm walking away now.

Comment: Related [Analogy Time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/213575)

Comment: @Braiam I totally agree with the analogy, and I'd love to provide more context, or *anything* to make the question clearer. But really, there is *so little* information out there on what I'm trying to do. Or at least, my Google-fu leads me to believe that there's little info. It's entirely possible my search abilities fail me, but I generally spend a *lot* of effort searching for answers, before I ever post a question at places like SO (hence, this is my first SO question after *years* of lurking / consuming).

Comment: @Paul what relevant code could be displayed here? It's like _"How do I get the current console front color?"_, where people are saying _"We can't answer that until you show your console writing code"_.

Comment: @Braiam no, not at all. It is quite clear what the OP is looking for, and it's specific enough to be answered with a couple of sentences and/or a few lines of code. Or so I hope, I do not know the answer. I know enough about networking and how an OS manages adapters to say so. That _you_ don't understand that is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: @CodeCaster just what you are responding at?

Comment: @Braiam to your "analogy time" link comment, from which I assume that you think the question should have been closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @CodeCaster you know what they say about assuming, right? Don't do it.

Comment: @Braiam then perhaps post somewhat more constructive comments than a three-word one from which it is not clear what point you're trying to make. What _do_ you want to say with that comment and how does if relate to the question being discussed?

Comment: The [c] tag is funny that way, [c++] has it as well.  The kind of questions asked are always either homework or pure language questions.  Actually *using* the language to solve a practical problem is never done.  Nobody mentions their compiler and operating system.  Anybody that stumbles in will have to deal with Olaf, god have mercy on your soul when you try to use a C api in a C++ program.  Really rather best to avoid the tag completely, consider [linux] instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting. Thanks! Info filed away for future reference...

Comment: @CodeCaster is entirely constructive: it helps the asker to put itself on the close voters shoes...

Comment: @Braiam no, some pictures explaining some close reasons do not explain why _you_ thought that the discussed close reason was valid for the linked question.

Comment: @scottbb as always with these questions where you know another tool that gets "more or less" what you want, try to see how they do it. iproute2 tool ip source code is out there. The others want at least that you have done a cursory glance to that information before asking.

Comment: @CodeCaster well... in my views it does.

Comment: @JeremyBanks no. I'm not complaining, I'm laughing out loud and every commenter that is scratching their heads... yes, it's hilarious :D

Comment: @Braiam Actually, I have done more than the cursory glance. I got lost in the weeds in the `iproute2` source. Regarding the "what have you done" being the bar for questions, I point to the first SO question I listed in this meta.SO question. In its *entirety*, it asked: "How can I get the IPv4 address of an interface in linux from C code? e.g. I'd like to get the IP address(if any) assigned to eth0". On topic, 45 votes, 49 for the accepted answer. What is standard?

Comment: You should instead search less than a year old examples... that way you will find the *current* standard.

Comment: @Braiam Fine, I'm open to learning. [Searching SO for "get ip address interface linux c created:1y"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+ip+address+interface+linux+c+created%3A1y). 10 results. Only 5 remotely related or similar in *topicality* to my question. 4 of those have no code to indicate what they tried. Regardless, the *reason* given for putting my OP on-hold was "off-topic". *Again*, based on the examples I cited (and even the 10 results in this search), what is the *standard for on-topic* that my question failed?

Comment: @scottbb: regarding the "standard for off-topic", there should have been a sub-reason that is in fact more important than that designation, because [around here "off-topic" doesn't actually mean what it says](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309103/603977) (see also [Shouldn't "off topic" be only about...off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086)) Unfortunately, I don't know what that sub-reason was and I don't believe it's possible to find out now that the question has been reopened.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thank you, good references. I certainly thought my question fit in line with the "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" standard. Regardless, even if I stumbled a bit, I learned, edited it to be clearer / concise / whatever was required to achieve my goal: *the question was reopened*.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for the discussion. Recap: I agree with the analogy; I certainly strived for the point it/you made. I tried to keep the OP short, but explain enough context so as to not have it closed because "unclear what you're asking". I didn't have any code to show where I was stuck, precisely because I know my efforts to find an answer to my problem weren't pointing me anywhere near a solution. I appreciate the constructive discussion. Thank you.

Comment: @CodeCaster Could you expand on your first comment? What do you mean by *and then mob voting happened.*? What mob?

Comment: @Tunaki the people who that comment applies to, know who they are.

Comment: @CodeCaster that is not good enough.  If you are going to label/libel SO users, you should have the guts to name them.  If you cannot put up, you should shut up.  This  'mob voting' accusation has been made before, the implication being that a set of users do not read questions  and follow votes only.  No actual evidence was produced before, and I suspect that there is none now.

Comment: @Martin I don't know how to search chat transcripts nor do I feel the need to do find that out right now, but my guess is that this question was mentioned in the SOCVR chat room. Either way, it was robo-reviewed by people who don't understand the subject of the question. The "offtopic - why isn't my code working needs more code" reason simply makes no sense at all to this question. Everybody can see the close-voters in the question's history, I don't need to repeat their names here.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am a room owner of the SOCVR chat room and I can confirm you that this question was not mentioned in the room.

Comment: @Tunaki if you carefully read my comments, you'll see that I'm not accusing anyone, I'm just posting my suspicions. If I had evidence, I wouldn't be posting comments but acting upon it instead. That being said, as I've said plenty of times before now here, the close reason was wrong, and my problem with this whole ordeal is that the closevoters don't seem to have paid much attention to the reason they picked, and I'm not convinced the question needed closing in the first place. Call it mob voting, call it robo-reviewing, the words used do not change the problem at hand.

Comment: It appears that this previous Meta question ([Does it violate Stack Overflow rules to answer this specific kind of “give me teh codez” question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269244/1677912)) is entirely relevant here - and could even be used as a duplicate target now that the specific complaint has been dealt with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has been reopened in the meantime, but let me give you my opinion on what happened.

I find your question very clear. It is to the point, and it contains enough information for someone to answer it. It can be answered by someone who has done this before, or by someone who has experience with the Linux socket and networking APIs, or by someone who can read manpages. Another viable answer would be *"You can't do this"*, if that is the case.

So the chosen close reason, which was:

> Off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Was entirely inappropriate. There was no code to show, you were asking what code to write to do this. The thing you're trying to do is query the OS for information by using OS-specific API calls.

That close reason would make just as little sense for a question like this:

> In C#, how do I get the current foreground color for the console?

You cannot show any relevant code for that, and the answer would be *"You can obtain it through the getter of the [`Console.ForegroundColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) property"*.

So in my opinion, the close-voters did not pay enough attention to which close reason they picked, and the question did not warrant being closed in the first place.

I don't know how the close-voters got to your question, maybe it was linked from elsewhere or they stumbled upon it in the review queue, but to them I would like to say: please defend in an answer here why you think this question warranted that close reason, or otherwise, try paying a little more attention to which close reason you think you need to pick - if any.

Comment: As one of the initial close voters I fully agree with this answer. I got the question the queue. I'll pay more attention / be more skip happy in the future.

Comment: @rene alright, thanks for owning up to it. I did not mean to offend the SOCVR chat in any way (see the comments under the questions), but it seemed like it was close-voted by many people in a short time without paying too much attention to the question's contents.

Comment: I don't mind if you question actions of the SOCVR and please ping me or any member if you suspect the room is involved. My philosophy with the room is to moderate posts to the best of our abilities within the rules, transparent and in cooperation with the meta crowd. We are active and with that we make mistakes. But we are also happy to help if moderation of posts is questioned.

Comment: I don't entirely agree that the close voters weren't paying attention (although certainly possible they weren't).  I have unfortunately seen this close reason used to close "No Research" questions.  While it isn't getting close to rampant misuse, it is the new "minimal understanding" close reason

Comment: Looking at the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36165017/timeline), 4 of 5 votes came from [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11734989).