# Are questions about programming problems that were caused by non-programming-related causes on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

Sometimes I read questions with answers that solved the problem without changing the code but instead suggested fixes for some external cause. I.e. programming problems that were caused by non-programming-related causes, leading to off-topic answers.

These questions border on the "No Longer Reproducible" close reason but don't match all the criteria. They still can be reproduced and they aren't caused by typos. Do these questions fit into this close reason or not?

I don't know if there needs to be a new close reason for these kinds of questions, perhaps like:

> Off-topic > Error in Code Caused by External Source > This question is about a programming problem that was caused by a non-programming-related cause. Such questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow because their resolutions are off-topic and completely unrelated to the code errors themselves.

Example of a question that fits under this made-up close reason:

> Question: PRAW is rejecting my credentials. Here is my code...
>
> Answer: I looked at your Reddit account and you're banned. That's why the API doesn't let you log in. You should get it sorted out with the Reddit admins or create a new account.

Are questions about programming problems that were caused by non-programming-related causes on-topic?

Comment: Of course they should. (I imagine the downvotes mean *that*, rather than the usual "I disagree".) Use "Not reproducible" – as it would work for others – or write your very own custom reason.

Comment: Hmm, no, this is a site for programmers.  They do get to deal with stuff that looks like a programming problem but might not be all the time.  We have interesting but unappreciated lives.  A heart surgeon must have it easier, she never has any trouble locating the bug.  If a library release acquires a nasty bug or the Internet burped while downloading it then that is certainly on topic, even though the OP had nothing to do with it.  If they couldn't debug their program because their car didn't start in the morning then, well, no of course.  Consider giving meta a break for a while btw.

Comment: @Hans _Programming_ happens within certain environments. I'd be happy to meet you at the Coffee Brewer Machine at 8:30 PM ;)

Comment: *"While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."* seems plenty applicable already.

Comment: @PaulCrovella that would be a [blatantly incorrect interpretation and an abuse of that close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348025/4639281)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of an interesting area. On the one hand, I can see where you're coming from here. The actual problem technically isn't programming. So if you're trying to do networking in programming, and your network goes off-line... that's not really something we can fix.

But on the other hand, we do handle problems that are not specifically programming, like compiler bugs. Here's some code that doesn't work, why? It turns out that it's not because of anything you did; it's because the tool you're using is broken. Not only is that not the fault of the asker, it's a question that has *value*, because odds are good other users of that compiler will likewise encounter the bug.

We don't "fix" compiler bugs either. You're unlikely to see someone post some snippet of GCC and explain how to correct it. The closest to a fix you're likely to get is a workaround.

So looking at the networking issue, that is something programmers can *detect*, even if we can't actually tell you how to fix it. That is, assuming that the code is reproducible and all errors from the networking protocols are provided, a programmer is uniquely equipped to be the one to tell you "this is indicative of a hardware problem, not a coding problem".

And that determination has value. Users would be able to search for some of these errors and find the solution (OK, broken network cards and Google don't exactly mix, but you get my point). So such questions do have utility.