# Should this question be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821532/system-data-sqlite-sqliteexception-command-error) with what I naturally thought was a useful answer, and the user up and deleted the question.

I'll admit, that was a bit irritating, but I'm not sure if the question and answer would even prove useful to future new users. To be honest, with so many "Why is water wet?" and "I want a pony!" questions from new users lately, it's getting hard to tell what a new user would find useful.

So, if you've got a minute, I'd just like to get some more eyeballs on the question.

[image]

Comment: The OP him/herself chose to delete it. Lesson: Be selective about which questions to answer as this was not a good question, nor was the OP well-behaved.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I agree completely; I'm usually *very* selective about answering. But, it seemed to me to be an error a new user might make with some regularity, so I answered it. (Bad Monkey!!)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: oh well

Comment: I don't think that question should get undeleted in its current state, but I can imagine a well written question that explains in words what's being attempted, such that someone could actually find your useful answer. Right now, what would someone have to search to find that question? "SQLite Exception Windows Form Applications"? I can't think of any conceivable way a user who needs your answer could find that question, so it would need some hefty editing before it could get undeleted.

Comment: @DavyM: The OP edited the question right before deleting, and the original query was much more extensive. I suspect the DV's were due to the impression that the OP was using code that they didn't even write, and just "threw their hands up" when it didn't work. So, we also have to examine the question of just how plausible the problem *really* is.

Comment: I'm not sure I would describe that earlier revision as *"much more extensive"* and I don't really see what's worth keeping about it before it was edited. If you feel that this site lacks something about `value()` not working with SQLite maybe add a well written self-answered Q&A about it instead? Sounds like a lot less work than trying to polish that linked question.

Comment: Since it does seem to be textbook vandalism I've undeleted and rolled back the question.

Comment: Well, putting the question on hold for "Typo" seems to be a *bit* of a stretch. Should I have made my answer a Community Wiki?

Comment: And the question is closed and going to be deleted anyways... and no, community wiki or not would end with the same result. If you really want to keep your answer around, **ask a question which deserves your answer**.

Comment: @DavyM truth be told I usually find answers with Google, not questions. As in I click the link and I jump directly to the answer. More often than not the only reason I have to go look at the question that belonged to the answer is to cast a vote on it.

Comment: @SamuelLiew How is it vandalism?  There was an extremely low quality question, it got downvotes and close votes because it wasn't useful or appropriate as a question for the site, so the author deleted it because they couldn't (or didn't want to) fix it.  That's exactly how the  system is *designed* to work, and isn't vandalism.  Deleting one's own low quality questions isn't vandalism.

Comment: @Servy FYI if you look in the revisions, the user did vandalize their post (deleting most of its content) before deleting it. I hadn't realized that until Samuel's comment; I saw the vandalized version and thought "of course that was deleted, there isn't even a question".

Comment: @Jeremy While it's annoying when people remove a lot of the content of a post a few seconds before deleting it, it's not really grounds for undeleting the content.  And of course the vast majority of the content removed *should* have been removed.  Most of it was just superfluous code not related to the error or noisy text.  The only text of value was a badly copied version of the error message.  But given that deletion of the post in all of the revisions is entirely fine, the point stands that undeletion isn't appropriate.

Comment: If you think a better written version of that question along with your answer would be valuable to others, why don't you write and self answer a new question about that topic?

Comment: @divibisan: That's the whole point of this question. I didn't think that. I wanted to get opinions about whether it was or not.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield The typo reason also contains the reason "or of no use to future readers". If a question is going to be of no use to future readers then that reason would apply even if it's not a typo. It's quite clear this question is not a typo question, so we have to assume the CVers voted for the reason that it won't be of use. See more on that subject by Shog: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348033/2756409

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, I've read that; I'm not buying it in this case.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield FWIW I think the question is of value to future readers (it was of value to me) and should not be closed, let alone deleted.

Comment: @TylerH: I was initially uncertain (hence the question), but as the discussion developed, I'm leaning more toward the interpretation that it's not really a plausibly repeatable problem. See my answer.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: *the original query was much more extensive* Yep. There was a lot more SQL there, none of which was relevant, and there wasn't any more textual information than there was when the post was deleted. Your answer was good, but the question itself IMO was not of sufficient quality to be of any use to future readers. I just looked again, and can't find anything in the deleted (either version) question that would have merited it not being closed. The poster chose to delete it, though (and could very well have done so after reading your answer).

Answer (score 4):

Well, the consensus appears to be "That depends". On its face, the question is not a bad question about a SQL query, aside from the seriously borked original title. All of the relevant information is presented; it doesn't require an MCVE; and all of the pertinent details about the technologies involved are included.

However, it's as plain as the nose on your face that the question is posted by a "zero-effort" user that is using code they got from somewhere and about which they have no idea how it works; so they have no idea why it doesn't work. The reason it doesn't work might as well have a strobelight on it.

So then we come to this Meta question: would the answer to this question be useful to future new users? Should it be undeleted?

On a side note, I'm aware that there is a common assumption that I asked this question because I wanted the question to be undeleted (presumably for the fake Unicorn points, which, I might add, at the time were zero). If that were the case, I would simply have raised a Mod flag for vandalism, but that's by-the-by, and since people wed to their assumptions tighter than they do to their spouses, there's nothing to be gained by belaboring the point.

One reasonable conclusion could be that the answer would only be useful to future users that are in the same boat as the OP, effort-wise. A new user (even a novice) that actually wrote a query like that would have at least some idea of what it did and how it did it, so they wouldn't ask that question in the first place.

A further complication was introduced when a Moderator undeleted the post right in the middle of the discussion, thereby proving the axiom that being a Moderator on Stack Overflow is a completely thankless job, and also proving the informal corollary that "sometimes you can't please any of the people, ever".

At that point, the discussion pretty much went off the rails, and people just started voting their irritation, which is understandable, if perhaps not constructive. The question was immediately close-voted for "Typographical error", which, objectively, is a blatantly flimsy pretext, but since the "Lacks basic understanding" close-reason is no longer available, it's not entirely unreasonable.

I'm left with the conclusion that the consensus, at least the *voting* consensus, is:

*That depends. Do we want to be useful to future users? Yes.  Do we want to be useful to "zero-effort" future users? No.*

which certainly seems reasonable enough.

Comment: @yivi: Just for my edification, should we not use blockquotes for thematic formatting?

Comment: Usually blockquoting something means that you're quoting it, not that you're just trying to format it thematically.

Comment: @DavyM: No kidding. :) I don't see a problem with it though, when the formatted text is plainly not a quote.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield The issue is that, by formatting it as a quote, you're essentially *telling us* it's a quote. So to avoid confusion, only format quotes as quotes. :-)

Comment: @TylerH: Ok, noted. (Laughed at, but noted) :)