# Close questions caused by confusing two similar variable names

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, typographical-error

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66690416/5005177) the problem was caused by confusing two similar variable names `show` and `showModal`. I believe it's very unlikely that this question will help others in the future, but it is not exactly a typo. I still voted to close this question as a typo for a lack of a better option.

Do you think that questions like this where confusing two variables should be closed and if so is "typo" the preferred reason to pick?

Comment: IMO, typo is fine. For questions like these to help future visitors, we have to be able to enumerate all possible misspellings of identifiers. Or at least relevant ones. But this is absurd. A more realistic solution is to create a canonical that explains the pattern to fix. However, that will create an absurd answer that will basically be "when you create an `a`, use `a`, not `b`". When you reduce the problem to "you have the wrong name", the solution becomes self-evident. You know what else narrows down the problem? A good MCVE/MRE - the issue should be revealed in the process of making one.

Comment: @VLAZ I'd say that in that instance the identifier was not really misspelled. It's just that OP created a higher level interface that accepts a property with a similar name `show` and then passes it down to a lower level interface that expects `showModal` but when passing it down OP failed to account for the different names. This most likely happens with languages like javascript that are not strictly typed and therefore not leading to a compiler error. I agree that when crafting an MCVE you will most likely stumble across those mistakes but we still see questions with that kind of mistake.

Comment: @VLAZ So if we agree that those questions are not helpful to others my questions simply would be: Which reason to vote for close should be picked?

Comment: As I said: IMO, typo is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348025/resolved-in-a-manner-unlikely-to-help-future-readers)

Comment: I'm sure you would agree with closure as a typo if the variables were `show` and `shwo` It's the same thing - a misspelled variable (see "different variable names" as "mental typo")

Comment: @Stephan I definitely would agree. In this instance it is somewhat harder to find as when expecting `show` but seeing `shwo` you can easily spot the error without having to look somewhere else for the name. But OP probably had a confirmation bias in expecting `showModal` and also seeing `showModal` when it was not the correct name in the first place. However you are correct that the outcome is pretty much the same for the js interpreter. Also the fact that there is no error message that others may encounter to find that question makes it very unlikely it will help future readers.

Comment: Not sure how it works for JS but in Dot Net, We have `.Show` and `.ShowDialog` So if someone is to use `.ShowDialog` and is using `.Show` or vice versa, we are to close it as typo? If yes, then this doesnt make sense...

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is not related. OP created an abstraction (a react component) with an interface that has `show` as a property. But the interface of the library he used in the implementation expects `showModal`. He just mistakenly thought that the name of the property in his abstraction also was `showModal` when it wasn't. This can only really happen in a language that is not strictly typed or when using plain strings as identifiers.

Comment: My JS is as good as my French... If I may say so :P Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @trixn With such questions, consider whether some future visitor with the same problem would be able to find the question, either using an external search engine or the internal SO search. With such errors, you usually have *no idea* what's causing the problem until it's explained, which makes searching very difficult, unless there's some kind of tell-tale error message. And if a question isn't findable by people with the same problem there's not much point keeping it on the system. So such questions get cleaned up by the Roomba, unless they have a positive scored or accepted answer.

Comment: @VLAZ "A more realistic solution is to create a canonical that explains the pattern to fix. However, that will create an absurd answer...." I consider that "here's how to extract relevant information from the error message, and how to work through the code to find a source of the problem" is actionable advice, which is how I ended up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631401 (which is loosely modeled on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722).