# When is a typo a reason for closure or to not answer a question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I ask this in reference to this question [image not showing up from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953377/image-not-showing-up-from-api/68953436#68953436).

And I read on https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions that "If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site." and it's what got me here.

The question is closed because it is "not reproducible or was caused by typos"

The user has a problem in the following line, which has a typo:

```
<img "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/" + ${meal.id} + "-90x90.jpg">
```

The `img` tag lacks the `src` attribute:

```
<img src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/" + ${meal.id} + "-90x90.jpg">
```

But even when the typo is fixed, the code still won't work. It is around a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and the user is attempting to concatenate the values, something that will just be part of the string, being a clear misunderstanding of template literals, but because he *also* had a typo, the question is instantly closed, should I just ignore questions with any typo in the code?

Comment: When `src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/" + ${meal.id} + "-90x90.jpg"` is wrong, then what will it result to?

Comment: The main idea of the Typo close reason is that the question is unlikely to help future visitors. If somebody spelled a variable wrong or forgot an attribute, it doesn't really seem like it's very helpful. There *are* some very common typos that catch a lot off-guard, e.g., using `=` instead of `==`. There are *usually* duplicates for those.

Comment: @Tom It will result to `src="https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/" + his img id + "-90x90.jpg"` on the final value, here an example https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-stonebraker-ksxrx?file=/src/index.js

Comment: *But even when the typo is fixed, the code still won't work.* is a perfectly valid reason to close a question.

Comment: It's a problem which hides another problem, not uncommon on software development. By not paying much attention and dumping the problem on Stack Overflow far too early, the question was not about the problem which actually mattered. A shame, but a low quality question nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The close reason is correct.

The OP's problem is that the image is not showing from the API.

The solution is to add the `src` attribute which will actually fix the problem (which is the image is not showing from the API), if there is any other problems that should be addressed, so it should be a separate question (But of course a good one), basically don't answer questions that are caused by typos or not reproducible. By answering these types of questions, you will actually harm Stack Overflow rather than improving it. Most of these questions will Roomba (which means that it will be deleted automatically), by answering them, you will prevent Roomba from doing its work.

[As the comment by @VLAZ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/862676), The main idea of "not reproducible or was caused by typos" close reason is to close questions that are likely won't help future users since there is a rare (low) percentage that users will do the *exact same* typo in the future, so it will less likely will help future users.

If you really want to help users, you may add a comment telling users that there is a typo in their code. Exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121861172). And flag these questions as "not reproducible or was caused by typos" (Flag > needs improvement > A community-specific reason > Not reproducible or was caused by a typo).

#### Summarize

**Don't** answer questions that are caused by a typo or not reproducible. Just add a comment (Optional) and/or Flag them as "not reproducible or was caused by typos" (Optional).

Comment: I mainly thought the typo was minor compared to the other mistake, do the same applies if a user ask a question that requires multiple "solutions"? I will leave comments on the next time

Comment: Except [do not pretend to be able to predict the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348025/resolved-in-a-manner-unlikely-to-help-future-readers/348033#348033)

Comment: I agree with the end result, but I would say that people should not worry about the Roomba in their interactions with posts. They should do things because it's the right thing to do, not because of some automated process.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree but if you will stop somthing good from doing good work and you will do something bad so you shouldn't do it, no?